# ¿Por qué no existe la palabra "marida"?

Tags: etimología, historia, género

El fememino de esposo es esposa. ¿Por qué "marido" no tiene un equivalente en femenino "marida"?

En el DLE se ve:

> [**marido**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OPnl0mR)
>
> Del lat. marītus.
>
> 1. m. Hombre casado, con relación a su cónyuge.

Si buscamos la palabra en latín [*marītus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maritus) se puede encontrar algo de información:

> **Adjective**
>
> *marītus* (feminine *marīta*, neuter *marītum*); first/second declension

Aunque acá se habla es de un adjetivo, al menos parece que en latín había una forma femenina. ¿Llegó esa forma femenina alguna vez al español o nunca pasó del latín?. En los matrimonios se dice: "los declaro marido y mujer". ¿Es  mujer/esposa el único femenino de "marido"?

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [Is it possible to refer to a wife as “una marida?”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17417/6915)

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18659/por-qu%c3%a9-yegua-y-no-caballa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según el [Charlton Lewis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dmaritus), la palabra latina usualmente usada como sustantivo era la masculina:

> **marītus** L.—As subst m., a married man, husband / V.—Of animals, the male

Según el [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmaritus1) existía también la forma plural y la femenina:

> II.B.3. In plur.: **mă-rīti**, **ōrum**, m., married people, man and wife (post-class.), Dig. 24, 1, 52 fin.: “novi mariti,” newly-married people, a young couple, App. M. 8, p. 201, 36.—
>
> III. **mărīta**, ae, f., a married woman, wife (poet. and postclass.): “marita,” Hor. Epod. 8, 13: “castae maritae,” Ov. F. 2, 139; id. H. 12, 175; Inscr. Orell. 2665; Inscr. Fabr. 299 al.; and freq. on epitaphs.

Estas dos acepciones son «post-class.», es decir, corresponden al latín postclásico (desde aproximadamente 200 E.C. hasta el medioevo), y también poéticas. El latín postclásico, nótese bien, era un latín generalmente usado como lengua literaria y litúrgica, y más cuanto más nos acercamos a la actualidad; vale decir, no es [latín vulgar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lat%C3%ADn_vulgar), que es de donde surgió el romance.

En el CORDE encuentro sólo dos instancias de *marida* como sustantivo en épocas no contemporáneas, en *[Los trabajos de Persiles y Segismunda](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=221217%5C022%5CC000O22122017220020476.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20marida%20or%20maridas%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0)* de Cervantes...

> *- Si va a decir la verdad, señores alcaldes, tan marida es Mari Cobeña de Tozuelo, y él marido della, como lo es mi madre de mi padre y mi padre de mi madre.*

... y en las *[Cartas del Caballero de la Tenaza](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=221217%5C022%5CC000O22122017220020476.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20marida%20or%20maridas%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1)* de Quevedo:

> *Si vuesa merced me quiere para mientras marida, o como para marido, o para entre marido, aquí me tiene corriente y moliente.*

En un par de escritos del siglo XX aparece *marida* como sustantivo pero el uso parece irónico; en los demás casos, todos bastante antiguos, se utiliza *marida* como adjetivo, sinónimo de *casada* (hay un dicho, aparentemente común porque aparece en varias formas similares, que va *La que mal marida nunca le falta qué diga*). De todas formas son apenas un puñado de instancias apenas.

Probablemente la forma femenina *marida*, que era poco usada en latín, cayó casi totalmente en desuso en latín vulgar y romance y terminó desapareciendo, aunque haya sido un par de veces rescatada por autores cultos. Por lo que parece no existe no sólo en castellano, sino en ninguna otra lengua romance: en portugués, italiano y francés se usa *mulher*, *femme* y *moglie* ("mujer", "mujer" y "esposa", respectivamente), y en rumano *soție* ("esposa", femenino de *soț* "esposo", del latín *socius* "compañero").